# Express Nodejs | express-ejs-layouts doesn't work with express-messages

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am struggling to connect my custom message template to my layout file.

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMgjX.png)

If I just call <%- messages() %> it will show flash message, but if I try to display custom it doesn't I copied the custom code from https://github.com/expressjs/express-messages so there can't be an error.

Comment: Can you give us a look at your route and ejs with the form please? Did you install connect-flash, and you're sending the message from a POST right? They are saved from the POST, PUT, DELETE's so you will see them on the next route, the GET. Let's see your code and I can help you. Make it easy for me to help.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for replying.

I have installed connect-flash, but I found out what is the problem. When I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-ejs-layouts it does not connect to my messages.ejs and no message is shown, once I install layouts it does not display, but it displays default message without a need for messages.ejs

in conclusion

---

- With express-ejs-layouts i can call ONLY <%- messages()%>
- Without express-ejs-layouts i can call <%- messages('messages',
  locals) %>

[app.post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mz5Xf.png)

[message.ejs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AMys.png)